# UITableView not selecting properly

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am working on an iPhone app, where I have a UITableView which is being populated with an XML feed through a URL.

Say for instance three of the cells are populated.

If I tap on the first cell nothing happens, however if I tap on the second or third cell, it takes me to the second screen related to cell one, and the same happens with the other cells - tap on it nothing, tap on another and it takes me to the second screen of the previous one selected.

I have never had this happen before and am rather confused.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                              reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    LocationsItem *atm = [[locations atms] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[atm atmName]];

    float distance = [[atm atmDistance] floatValue];
    NSString *distanceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f miles from current location", distance];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:distanceString];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    LocationsItem *atm = [[locations atms] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    ATMDetailsController *detailsController = [[ATMDetailsController alloc] init];

    [detailsController setCurrentATM: atm];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailsController animated:YES];

}
```

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Please post your cellForRowAtIndexPath: code

Comment: Sounds like your indexing in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is off by one, but without seeing some relevant code, it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for looking, I have pasted some code above.

Comment: Try putting `NSLog(@"%@ called on row:%d with atm:%@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),indexPath.row,atm.atmName);` near the end of both of the methods you posted. What version of Xcode & iOS are you on?

Comment: I am using Xcode 4.2, and have the Deployment Target set to iOS 4.2. I pasted the your statement into both methods. 
If I tap on cell 0, then on cell 1 I get:
tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: called on row:0 with atm:HSBC, Bridlington
The statement is not produced from the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: I've just noticed my problem - I am using "didDeselectRowAtIndexPath", not "didSelectRowAtIndexPath".  Silly me.

Comment: Don't know how I didn't see that either. Be sure to write an answer to your question and accept it to help if it catches someone else.

Comment: Will do, however can't do it until tomorrow as my reputation is too low.

Comment: damn you autocomplete!!!! Same problem here! :(

Comment: I did the same thing!  DYAC!  Still need to accept the answer.

Answer (score 9):

You answered your own question.  The issue is that you used `tableView:deselectRowAtIndexPath:` instead of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

What is noteworthy is that this is from the unfortunate fact that `deselect` comes before `did` in the dictionary, and therefore, xcode's normally awesome code completion hinks you!

Now to go get those hours of debugging back!

Comment: Same issue I had. Wasted an hour trying to figure out what was going on. Need to pay more attention to autocomplete and syntax, lol.